# How remove escaped sequences (e.g. \"escaped string\") using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, match

I am trying to remove quoted sequences from a string. For the example below my script works fairly:

```
import re
doc = ' Doc = "This is a quoted string: this is cool!" '
cleanr = re.compile('\".*?\"')
doc = re.sub(cleanr, '', doc)
print doc
```

Result (as expected):

```
' Doc =  '
```

However when I have escaped string inside the quoted sentence I am not able to remove the escaped sequence using the pattern that I think would be the right one:

```
import re
doc = ' Doc = "This is a quoted string: \"this is cool!\" " '
cleanr = re.compile('\\".*?\\"') # new pattern
doc = re.sub(cleanr, '', doc)
print doc
```

Result

```
'Doc = this is cool!'
```

Expected:

```
'Doc = "This is a quoted string: " '
```

Does anyone knows what is happening? If the pattern `'\\".*?\\"'` is wrong what would be the right one?

Comment: When you send the first and second expressions to the `re` module, they both end up as the same expression because of runaway escaping. Use raw strings to avoid this issue.

Comment: That question is very well asked and clear, I really don't see any reason for downvoting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc` doesn't contain any escaped characters, so your regex doesn't match.

Add the [`r`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l) prefix to the string, which means that it should be treated as a *raw* string, ignoring escaped codes.

Try this:

```
>>> doc = r' Doc = "This is a quoted string: \"this is cool!\" " '
>>> cleanr = re.compile(r'\\".*?\\"')
>>> re.sub(cleanr, '', doc)
' Doc = "This is a quoted string:  " '
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the prompt answer. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Note that this answer assumes that you are able to define your `doc` as a literal in your code. If you can do that, great. If you're getting it from another source, you better hope that it includes a literal backslash.